# Graph api /users/{id}/mailFolders/{id}/messages/delta only lists up to 5000 mails

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I've met an issue that users/{id}/mailFolders/{id}/messages/delta in graph api lists only up to 5000 mails.

I've kept updating skip tokens, however, for all the tenants and users I attempt on, I can list only up to 5000 mails in total (although they have more than 10000 mails) when the delta token is obtained.
Note that I do not use any $filter.

Thank you, Sincerely

Comment: I've attempted to set $top to be more than the mails count (eg.10000), and all mails can be pulled.
However, the page size will change from our odata.maxpagesize to 512.
Thank you, Sincerely

Comment: The grant flow I've used is client credential grant flow.